# How can I use Intellisense in VSC with pybricks (micropython)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, micropython

I want to use it to code my EV3 brick. I read all the answers on stackoverflow for similar questions, but none of them helped.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. It should not be edited into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the [LEGO EV3 Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lego-education.ev3-micropython)?

And you can install the `pybricks` like this `pip install git+https://github.com/pybricks/pybricks-api@master`

Then you need to import it like this:

```
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
```

You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/pybricks/support/issues/10) for more details, some people others had to submit a feature request of this early.

Comment: I did all of this and it still doesn't work, I set up a virtual environment, installed pybricks and the extension, and did everything in your link

Comment: Edit: It worked, I will soon post the solution

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to comment out the last two settings in settings.json